# Layout diferente em janela anonima e outros navegadores

Tags: html, css, layout, layout-responsivo

Estou desenvolvendo um site simples com html,css, caso seja necessario eu coloco o código posteriormente.

mas a questão seria estou usando grids com row e col do bootstrap, quando abro do chrome normal o layout fica todo esquito parece que não está com o css certo, agora se eu abro em uma janela anonima o mesmo site ou no mozilla aparece certo como deveria.
estou testando localmente o site.

HTML

```
    <div class=" container content-wrapper pro">
            <div class=" row" >
                <div class="col-t">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Chave de fenda philips</h4>
                    <img src="img/p1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <h4 class="card-title">Chave de fenda philips</h4>
                    <img src="img/p1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                </div>
             <div class="col-t">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Chave de fenda philips</h4>
                    <img src="img/p1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <h4 class="card-title">Chave de fenda philips</h4>
                    <img src="img/p1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>

                </div>          
             <div class="col-l">
                <h4 class="card-title">Chave de fenda philips lateral</h4>
                <img src="img/p1.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                 <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                     <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
        <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
        <div class="rodape">
            <?php
                include("footer.php");
            ?>
        </div>
</div>
```

HEAD

```
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Ionicons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<!-- jvectormap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
 .pro{
    padding-top:20%;
 }


 .col-t{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 2%;
    width: 28%;
    justify-content: center ;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
 }

.col-l{

text-align: center;
 margin-left: 3%;
  width: 36%;
 justify-content: center ;
  max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 }


    .wrapper{ 
        background-color: #ffffff;
        margin:2%;
        margin-left:5%;
        margin-right:5%;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: 90%;

    }
    .home{
    color :black;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Chrome normal 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Chrome janela anonima
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Mozilla

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: "caso seja necessario eu coloco o código posteriormente", sim, precisa, leia como elaborar um [mcve] inclusive. Se puder postar os prints das respectivas telas também ajudará bastante.

Comment: feito colocado codigo e imagens

Comment: E os prints das telas diferentes?

Comment: colocado desculpa por nao ter colocado antes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que de alguma forma o Chrome em janela Anônima deve gerenciar as indexações de forma diferente... Digo isso, pq eu peguei seu código aqui e usei o template inicial sugerido na indexação e funcionou perfeitamente. O seu `<head>` foi montado em desacordo com o que sugere a documentação....

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vc tem que verificar exatamente a ordem em que esta importando as dependências do Bootstrap (CSS/jQuery/Bootstrap.JS). Aqui na documentação eles falam como deve ser o ***template inicial*** https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#template-inicial. Além disso, recomento que de um `Ctrl+F5` no navegado para forçar a limpar o cache.

Aqui tem o seu código funcionando perfeitamente no Chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <style>
    .pro {
      padding-top: 20%;
    }


    .col-t {
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 2%;
      width: 28%;
      justify-content: center;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

    .col-l {

      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 3%;
      width: 36%;
      justify-content: center;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }


    .wrapper {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      margin: 2%;
      margin-left: 5%;
      margin-right: 5%;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      width: 90%;

    }

    .home {
      color: black;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #D3D3D3;
      overflow: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class=" container content-wrapper pro">
    <div class=" row">

      <div class="col-t">
        <h4 class="card-title">Chave de fenda philips</h4>
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
        <h4 class="card-title">Chave de fenda philips</h4>
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-t">
        <h4 class="card-title">Chave de fenda philips</h4>
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
        <h4 class="card-title">Chave de fenda philips</h4>
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-l">
        <h4 class="card-title">Chave de fenda philips lateral</h4>
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
          content.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <div class="rodape">
    <?php
        include("footer.php");
    ?>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, sou bem iniciante na parte de layout =(.

Comment: @GabriellaSelbach sem problemas, sempre leia a documentação ajuda muito e deve ser um hábito. Se resolveu ai fico feliz em ter ajudado []´s